# Parallel gateway and exclusive gateways combination

Tags: jbpm, activiti, bpmn, business-process-management

I'm trying to model a process where two checks run in parallel, and the process continues when both of them are successful. Otherwise (if any of them fails) the process should be terminated, without waiting for the other one's result. Is the following diagram correct?

[image: BPMN diagram]

Also, if after any failed check I wanted to have a single flow, what would be the recommended way to model it?

P.S. I can't use a subprocess or complex gateways at that point in the model. I will be implementing the model in Activiti, if there are any specific recommendations for it.

Answer (score 3):

Your process model is correct, because you are using a **terminate end event**. *If a token reaches a Terminate End Event, the entire Process is abnormally terminated* ([BPMN specification, page 436; page 456 in PDF](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0.2/PDF).

Now to your additional question: *Also, if after any failed check I wanted to have a single flow, what would be the recommended way to model it?*.

I assume you want to trigger a specific process flow **the first time either of the checks fails**.
If you want to do this by using 'basic' elements only, you need to implement some low-level logic, for example a counter that is increased with each failing check and a gateway that manages the process flow based on the value of this counter:

[image]

However, I advice you to **not use such work-arounds to manage concurrency**. In the example above, it is at least theoretically possible that both *increase rejection counter* activities are executed *before* either token reaches the *Rejection counter == 1?* gateway.

Instead, I recommend using a sub process, which Activiti actually supports (see the [Activiti docs](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnSubprocessAndCallActivity)).

The sub process terminates as soon as one of the checks fails or when both checks pass. The main process decides whether to send a confirmation or whether to handle a failure based on the result of the sub process (my diagram assumes the sub process result is written to a variable the main process can access):

[image]

Like this, you let BPMN (respectively: Activiti) do the heavy lifting when it comes to concurrency and you can focus on business logic aspects.

**Note**: As alternative to the exclusive gateways that handle the check results, you could use attached error events ([Activiti supports error events as well](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnErrorEventDefinition)). However, I assume you don't consider a failing check a technical error, but rather an alternative path of the business logic of your process.